# Question on Frobenius Reciprocity

Tags: representation-theory

I have in my notes the statement of Frobenius reciprocity in the following two ways:

> If $H\leq G$ and suppose that we have $\chi_1$ a character of $G$ and $\chi_2$ a character of $H$. Then:
>   $$\langle \chi_1,\chi_2\uparrow^G\rangle_G=\langle\chi\downarrow_H,\chi_2\rangle_H$$

I also have it stated in the following way:

> Suppose that we have $f:H\rightarrow GL(V)$ and $f':G\rightarrow GL(V)$ then we have that there is an isomorphism of the hom sets, that is:
>   $$Hom_G(f',f\uparrow ^G)\cong Hom_H(f'\downarrow_H,f)$$

What I am failing to see is why these two statements are equivalent  (or really that related)

Could somebody explain the correspondence here?

Comment: The key property is “semisimple”. Homomorphisms and inner products both just count matching simple modules. It is important that $V$ be a vector space over a splitting field (of both $H$ and $G$) whose characteristic does not divide the order of the finite group $G$. For instance, $G$ finite and $V$ a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. More general statements of Frobenius reciprocity are common. The Hom statement continues to be true, but the inner product one needs many adjustments.

Comment: I would like to add one thing to Jack Schmidt's statement. The Hom statement is really a statement about tensor product being left-adjoint to Hom. In fact, the "more correct" version of that statement puts the induction on the left and the restriction on the right. In the case of finite groups, it makes no difference but it does for other inductions: Lie algebras for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\def\Ind{\mathrm{Ind}}$
$\def\Hom{\mathrm{Hom}}$
Ok. So let's translate the statement about characters into a statement about irreducible representations.

First, note that both the Hom property, and the character inner product distribute over taking direct sums of representations. So, it suffices to show why
$$\langle \chi_{V}, \chi_{\Ind^{G}_{H} W} \rangle_{G} = \langle \chi_{V|_{H}}, \chi_{W}\rangle_{H}$$
and 
$$\Hom_{G}(V, \Ind^{G}_{H} W ) \cong \Hom_{H}(V|_{H}, W)$$
are equivalent for $V$ an irreducible representation of $G$ and $W$ an irreducible representation of $H$.

Now, in the case where the representations are irreducible, Schur's Lemmma tells us that
$$\Hom_{G}(V, \Ind^{G}_{H}W) \cong \Hom_{H}(V|_{H}, W)$$
says exactly that the number of times the irreducible $H$-representation $W$ appears in $V_{H}$ is the same as the number of times that the irreducible $G$ representation $V$ appears in $\Ind^{G}_{H}W.$

On the other hand, because characters of irreducible representations form an orthonormal basis for the inner product,
$$\langle \chi_{V}, \chi_{\Ind^{G}_{H} W}\rangle_{G}$$
is exactly the number of times $V$ appears in $\Ind^{G}_{H}W$ and 
$$\langle \chi_{V|_{H}}, \chi_{W}\rangle_{H}$$
is exactly the number of times $W$ appears in $V_{H}$. So the equality of the inner products also gives the exact same data that the equality of the $\Hom$'s did.